# Why would concatenating feature vectors lead to better estimates?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, ridge-regression, dimensionality-reduction

I wish to estimate the state of a system from two separate and disparate observations. A simple approach that I have seen in some literature is to combine the feature vectors (observations) by simply concatenating them. So if the first observation is denoted $x \in \Re^{10}$ and the second is denoted $y \in \Re^5$, we obtain a single (composite) feature $z \in \Re^{15}$.

I have only seen this technique being applied (seemingly blindly) without any discussion as to what is actually going on "under the hood".

**Questions**

1. When does this approach make sense and when does it not make sense? It would be great to see an example of what is taking place and why the approach works or does not work.
2. Is there anything that must be done to the two features ($x$ and $y$) before concatenating them? (e.g. scaling/normalisation?)
3. Is there anything that might assist this approach? (e.g. dimensionality reduction)

Comment: By concatenating I would imagine something like stacking, while you mean binding/juxtaposing. 
While in general more data is indeed a good thing, it it not necessarily the case. Particularly in your scenario where it is unclear what the data is used for. Could you please be more specific regarding what you are trying to do with the data?

Comment: I am using the data to learn a mapping between the input space (features) and the output space (system state) using ridge regression. I am doing this for each sensor type separately, which gives two distinct mappings. By concatenating the two feature types, I hope to learn a new mapping that provides better estimates than if either of the two sensor-specific mappings were used with their associated feature.

Comment: So your $x$ and $y$ are essentially simultaneous measurements from two sensors that you're concatenating into a single measurement?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.